# load a new page when an html's selector changes without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, selector

How can I (if at all) load a new page when an html's selector changes if javascript is disabled in the browser.

Can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "html's selector"?

Comment: I think he is talking about a "redirect" select tag

Comment: yes please elaborate, I'm curious too.

Comment: Ooooh, I think i know what he means, when someone changes a select box!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you mean the html select box having some page titles displayed and as soon as the user selects one of them the new page showes up.

This is not possible with out javascript - the only thing you could do is to add a submit button.

```
<noscript><input type="submit" value="go!"></noscript>
```

This button would only be displayed if javascript is not activated.

Comment: "This is not possible with javascript" -- Do you mean to say "This is only possible with Javascript"?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot reload a page when a `select` box changes (if that's your question) without using a scripting language or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Without a scripting language (that would be JavaScript if you want to be cross-browser), most form elements are "dumb", they hold their state and display user feedback.
So if you want to select a new page after selecting it in a form (combo box, list, radio buttons...), you have to add a submit button to send the choice to a server, and have a server side script handling the choice and serving the right page.

The good old Web 1.0 way... :-)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. With HTML only, changing the selected option makes the value of that option to be sent to the server upon submit (either via the Enter key or a submit/button element). You can eventually set up the receiving script to send back a HTTP Redirect based according to the selected option.

**You shouldn't**. This kind of navigation widget implies the use of a mouse: somebody using the keyboard to navigate the page cannot even select the second option at all (as soon as the down arrow is pressed once the `onchange()` event activates). Do the right thing and add a submit button, with the page change activated by the `onsubmit()` event.